# Docker: Unable to access mysql container remotely

Tags: mysql, docker

I am using docker toolbox v17.03 in Windows 10 Home. I pulled latest mysql server and run the container.

```
> docker image pull mysql:latest

   > docker container run --detach --name=test-mysql --env="MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypassword" mysql

   > docker logs test-mysql
```

I am able to see mysql running. I then moved to Sql client and used the ipaddress (given by docker-machine ip). I get Access denied. I also tried the ip address from docker inspect test-mysql, same result )

Not sure what is wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

I think I found the problem. I didn't map the port. As soon as I change the docker run as follows , I am able to connect via ip address of docker-machine

```
> docker container run --detach --name=test-mysql --env="MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypassword" -p 3306:3306 mysql
```